# Excel VBA: copy row cell on specific number format in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have an acces export file in xlsx, with the first column being a number.
There are two types of numbers: (YY)YYXXXX and YY/X(.X).XX
Some examples.

20002024
20052028
974021
94/1.1.03
93/5.02
981017

I want to export only the rows that have 1 next to the year. So 981019 YES, 982016 NO. 90/1.1.04 YES, 91/5.01 NO.
To go about this i THINK i need to check if the cell contains a "/" if so copy the cell if the number next to / is "1". If not export the cell if the fourth last number is 1.

```
Sub copyrows()

Dim tfCol As Range, Cell As Object

Set tfCol = Range("A:A")

For Each Cell In tfCol

    If InStr(1, Cell, "/", 1) Then
        If Cell.Value = "??/1*" Then


        Cell.EntireRow.Copy
        Sheet2.Select 'Substitute with your sheet
        ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If

    ElseIf Cell.Value = "*1???" Then

    Cell.EntireRow.Copy
        Sheet2.Select 'Substitute with your sheet
        ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
Next

 End sub
```

This code is not working. I really doubted the whole `If Cell.Value = "??/1*"` would have worked. It clearly doesn't. It's also very... slow. so i think I'm doing something wrong.

Any ideas on how to do this?
If I find this out I'd make a prompt to make people select the number that has to be separated.
Thanks.

Comment: But none of your examples have either **(** or **)** ??

Comment: try something like this: If Cell.Value Like "??/1*" Then

Comment: no, that's because i meant that some (pre-2000) are written with two numbers, and the post 2000's are written with  4 numbers. 20052028 vs 974021. Same with the extra .X after the slash. 94/1.1.03 vs 93/5.02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data in A1 to A5

```
Sub copyrows()
    Dim tfCol As Range, Cell As Object
    Set tfCol = Range("A1:A5")
    For Each Cell In tfCol
        If InStr(Cell, "/") > 0 Then
            If Cell.Value Like "??/1*" Then
                Cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheet2.Range("A" & Sheet2.Range("A" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            End If
        ElseIf Cell.Value Like "*1???" Then
            Cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheet2.Range("A" & Sheet2.Range("A" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT 1**

Actually your code should be like below. Kindly replace Sheet2 with your destination sheet name.

```
Sub copyrows()
    Dim tfCol As Range, Cell As Object
    Set tfCol = Range("A1:A5")
    For Each Cell In tfCol
        If InStr(Cell, "/") > 0 Then
            If Cell.Value Like "??/1*" Then
                Cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheet2.Range("A" & Sheet2.Range("A" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            ElseIf Cell.Value Like "*1???" Then
                Cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheet2.Range("A" & Sheet2.Range("A" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This give me an  424 object needed error at  `Cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheet2.Range("A" & Sheet2.Range("A" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)` But the detection seems to be going great! Now the copying in itself. Might this be a problem with the sheet name?

Comment: you can try Worksheets("destinationsheetname") instead of Sheet2